# Getting double value from the quotient of integers

Tags: java

```
int velMperMin = 667;
int distM = 70;
double movT = (distM/velMperMin)*60;
```

`movtT` must be equal to `6.30`, but it's `0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to cast one of the operands of the division to be a double value. Like this:

```
double movT = ((double)distM/velMperMin)*60;
```

Your code performs integer division `distM/velMperMin` and that results in `0`. You then multiply that by 60. Still `0`. Then you convert to double and now it is `0.0`.

Casting one of the operands to `double` ensures that the division will be a floating point division rather than an integer division and will yield the result you expect.

Comment: or he just could define them as double.

Comment: @Vash Maybe, but sometimes you may have underlying variables that are naturally integers but you then want to perform floating point arithmetic with them.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to fix this is to multiple by a `double` first.

```
double movT = 60.0 * distM / velMperMin;
```

Answer (score 1):

the result of `int/int` is `int` (70/667 = 0.xxx, which is 0). You have to cast at least one `int` to `double` before dividing:

```
double movT = ((double) distM/velMperMin)*60;
```

Or just define one of the variables as double.

Answer (score 1):

Since `70 / 667` is `0`, `0 * 60` is `0`, too.

Answer (score 0):

distM and velMperMin are both integers and dividing them equals to 0, because the result is less than one and will be cut to a whole int number. Multiplying zero with 60 is still zero.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal: when using integers 70/667 is 0, where as when using a double it would result in 0,1049. Try changing the velMperMin and distM to doubles.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have refer to division performed on integer type.

When you divide integer, in result you will have also an integer. In your case you divide 70 by 667. This give 0 and 10494... rest. So the final result is zero is we do not have place to store the decimal values.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get into int division or you'll get int result.

```
Double velMperMin = new Double(667);
Double distM = new Double(70);
Double movT = ( distM / velMperMin * 60 );
```

Comment: Don't you mean `double` rather than `Double` ?

Comment: Nope. That's a wrong conclusion. You can use either the primitive double or Double. The thing is: don't expect a double (or Double) result from an int division, as other SO said